# waf pkg-config uselib_store variable

Tags: python, gstreamer, configure, waf

I m trying to set the include path for gstreamer for one of my project using waf . I think doing something like this should get the path

```
def configure(conf):                                                              
    conf.check_cfg(package='gstreamer-0.10', args='--cflags --libs',              
            uselib_store='GSTREAMER')
```

The above code would get translated on the command line into something like this

```
vickey@tb:~$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10
-pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lxml2 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
```

the docs suggest that the it will Store the flags to the uselib variable GSTREAMER, and raise a configuration error if the package cannot be found.

when I try to print the value GSTREAMER using

```
print(GSTREAMER)
```

I dont get the values . Are the values getting stored at some other place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 1 def options(opt):                                                               
 2     opt.load("compiler_cxx")                                                    
 3                                                                                 
 4 def configure(conf):                                                            
 5     conf.check_cfg(package='gstreamer-0.10', args='--cflags --libs',            
 6             uselib_store='GSTREAMER')                                           
 7                                                                                 
 8     print (conf.env.LIB_GSTREAMER);                                                                   
 9                                                                                 
10 def build(bld):                                                                 
11     subdirs = []
```